# Ugly dynamic google icons - any remedy?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-visualization

I'm trying to make custom icons for GM API v3 (I want numbers 1-20, all pins same size) and I found [Dynamic icons in Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons.html):

[image] [image] [image] [image]

( http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.65|0|FF8800|14|_|1 )

You see that "1" and "11" are not centered nicely! Any thoughts?

So nice API and so ugly icons!

---

PS: note that this API is now deprecated, [and no remedy has been found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11318672/684229).

Comment: @skaffman, don't edit the tags, it's ["google chart api"](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api), not "google charts api".

Comment: @Charles, the same applies to you!

Comment: @Thomas, it's always best to use existing tags rather than create new ones.  In this specific case, if you feel the tag is incorrectly spelled, please feel free to post on Meta about a rename of the tag or simply retag all of the 28 questions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Some combination of sizes are better, but it looks there is always one pixel too much on the right.

Or may be a desperate hack like:

```
<style>
    .pin{
        background:url(http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.65|0|FF8800|14|_|) no-repeat 50% 50%;
        width:29px;
        height:44px;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;
        padding-top:6px
    }
</style>

    ...

<div class="pin">1</div>
<div class="pin">2</div>
<div class="pin">3</div>
<div class="pin">4</div>
<div class="pin">5</div>
<div class="pin">11</div>

    ...
```

Comment: this will not work with google, as the markup is done by google itself. You would need to hack into google's markup, maybe by modifying DOM or something.

Comment: `http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.7|0|FF8800|14.5|_|1` feel less wrong